# Bootstrap carousel not working with php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to modify an existing carousel by loading data from an SQL instead of hardcoding it. But, after fetching the data from SQL using PHP the controls of the carousel is not working.

When I checked the source, the contents of all slides are added correctly obtained from the database.

FYI - I also have another carousel on the same page which is working fine. So, I think all the requirements will be loaded correctly.

Below is my code:

```
    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <!-- Query from db -->
        <?php
        $sql='SELECT * FROM Books LIMIT 6';
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); ?>
        <!-- start of while loop -->
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>  
        <?php if ($row[bookID] == 1) echo '<div class="item active">'; 
                                else echo '<div class="item">'; ?>
            <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $row[thumb]; ?>');">
                <a href="books.php?page=<?php echo $row[bookID]; ?>" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row[thumb]; ?>" class="img-responsive" 
                          alt="<?php echo $row[name_small]; ?>">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption portfolio1">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-name">
                                <h4><strong><?php echo $row[name_small]; ?></strong>
                                    <small><?php echo $row[second_title]; ?></small>
                                </h4>
                                <hr>
                                <p><?php echo $row[mini_desc]; ?></p>
                                <p><strong>First Published :</strong>
                                    <?php echo $row[first_published]; ?></p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div><?php } ?> 
            <!-- end of while loop -->
        </div>


    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div> 
</section>
```

I tried comparing the code to my old carousel and everything looks the same. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I have never tried it without, but do the associative array element names need quotes in them? $row[bookID] vs $row['bookID']. I always assumed it was required, but now I am wondering if that is true. I feel like it would use a constant instead of the key name.

Comment: I have not tried using '   ' before and it always used to work. I tried to change it everything to with ' ' but still no difference.

Comment: Just deleted my comment by accident... After the while loop there is a close div tag. Is that to close the carousel-inner div?

Comment: Yes, that is to close the carousel-inner div.

Comment: If that close div after the loop is intentional I think there is an extra close div at the end of the code. Unless that belongs to a div that comes before the snippet.

Comment: @CMiller That was the error. My editor did not pick up the <div> as it was inside ' '. It is working now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your condition

```
if($row[bookID] == 1)
```

It can or not have bookID equal to 1 in your database data !
To prevent it, use this

```
<?php $i = 1; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>  
      <div class="item <?= ($i == 1) ? 'active' : '' ?>">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $row[thumb]; ?>');">
            <a href="books.php?page=<?php echo $row[bookID]; ?>" class="portfolio-box">
                <img src="<?php echo $row[thumb]; ?>" class="img-responsive" 
                      alt="<?php echo $row[name_small]; ?>">
                <div class="portfolio-box-caption portfolio1">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                        <div class="project-name">
                            <h4><strong><?php echo $row[name_small]; ?></strong>
                                <small><?php echo $row[second_title]; ?></small>
                            </h4>
                            <hr>
                            <p><?php echo $row[mini_desc]; ?></p>
                            <p><strong>First Published :</strong>
                                <?php echo $row[first_published]; ?></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
     </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Does the class name in your first div need php tags around it?

Comment: Yes, forgetten ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this end of your loop:

```
                </div><!--portfolio-box-caption-->
            </a>
        </div><!--fill-->
    </div><!--item-->
<?php } ?><!-- end of while loop -->
```